# Is there an area to ask a question about how a company uses data science?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, policy

My question is: What data science tools does Khan Academy use to track student performance? More specifically: I'm curious as to how they track their performance in relation to a student that is not using Khan Academy and with common core standards.  Or if they attempt to predict student performance? Or how they might see if schools do better after employing their product?  (Within the scope of data science/statistics)

Is there an area of this site that I can ask this question?

Comment: Why not ask them? Otherwise -- if they don't reply -- I can't see that any one can answer this. Present and past employees are presumably bound by legal or ethical constraints; the overwhelming majority, the rest of us, can't know what isn't documented.  Whether it's on-topic is trickier. I just can't see that it is answerable. I do think it could be too broad even in principle.